# Selenium: try/except - driver.driver.find_element_by_xpath().click - Cannot to pass "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException"

Tags: selenium, try-except

I´m trying try/except here:

```
try:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/article/table/tbody/tr[10]/td/a").click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/article/table/tbody/tr[11]/td/a").click()
```

I always get: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/article/table/tbody/tr[10]/td/span[1]"}

Notes:

1. I have tried:"try/except"
2. I have tried: "try/except NoSuchElementException"
3. "from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException"
4. I have tried:

```
try:
    test = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/article/table/tbody/tr[10]/td/a")
    test_click = test.click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/article/table/tbody/tr[11]/td/a").click()
```

Still cannot make it work.

Comment: Please provide ulr or DOM details to replicate your issue

Comment: I start in one url (too long to be written here) and I finish in:  <https://www.biznes-polska.pl/wyniki-przetargow/19579154/>  But I´m introducing username and pasword to get there. The xpath is correct, when I try the correct one it´s working.

Answer (score -1):

You can try below solution to avoid synchronization error .

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
          EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, your element )))
except TimeoutException as ex:
            print ex.message
```

Comment: without proper details I cant help you . I would request you to provide url / DOM so that I can look into it. Most probably your element is present in the iframe or xpath which you are providing is incorrect.

Comment: Second path (except:) is correct, first one (try:) no, because when I try without the try/except is running perfect. It should work... Is there anyway I can post or send full HTML content??

Comment: @Jorsan : you need to be very specific which element you are trying to access. i think you need to login to your account if you are availble lets enter into chat room

Comment: I´m in room for selenius